# WordPress Make Customizer Public for Demo purposes

Tags: wordpress

I created a WordPress theme that uses the built in customizer. For demo purposes I would like to make the customizer public, so that anyone can use it without the need to login.
I saw several other themes doing this, even have the entire admin panel public and it seems to create some sort of instance, so other users viewing the same page are not being affected, however I could not find any tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The guys over at https://ninjademo.com/ seems to be doing exactly what I was looking for. Also, each user that visits the demo, will automatically have their own sandbox, so when they fiddle around in the demo, it will not affect other users who are viewing the demo.